# Indenting entire list items after using ::before to create bullets

Tags: css

I'm using the following to add a custom bullet character before `<li>` tags:

```
.cb-entry-content ul, .cb-sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;  
}
.cb-entry-content li::before, .cb-sidebar li::before {
    content: "•";
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #821019;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

How can I now indent the entire `<li>` item, so that the whole item is indented in relation to the bullet? Normally with `<li>` you'd accomplish this with `list-style-position: outside;`, but that won't work here. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

edit: Sorry, I don't think I was totally clear- I'd like for the indenting to continue after line breaks- so that the bullets are to the left, and the entire `<li>` item is indented after that. Currently, the text wraps under the bullet after a line break.

Comment: `li {text-indent: 1rem}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with negative margin to get the effect you want to, please see the example below.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;  
}
li::before {
  content: "•";
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #821019;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul.with-margin {
  margin-left: 10px; 
}

.with-margin li::before {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
</ul>

<ul class="with-margin">
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
  <li>Looooooooooooong text is very long, like it might even be multiple rows and that kills the custom style of your list items</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That looks like a solution! Thank you!

Comment: @gbrillon If this was your solution, could you mark it as 'answered'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin` or `text-indent`, either works.

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hjorth/pgoh0emy/5/)**

```css
ul.custom {
    list-style-type: none;  
}

ul.custom li:before {
    content: "•";
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #821019;
    font-weight: 700;
}

ul.custom li:nth-child(1) {
  text-indent: 1em;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul.custom li:nth-child(2):before {
  margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="custom">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was totally clear- I'd like for the indenting to continue after line breaks- so that the bullets are to the left, and the entire `<li>` item is indented after that. Currently, the text wraps under the bullet after a line break. Sorry if I wasn't clear!